# Avoid a form from being submitted when pressing "Enter" button within a text input

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to stop a form from submitting while pressing "Enter" button within a text.

```
<form >
    <input id="a" name="a" type="text"/>
    <input id="address" name="address" type="text" maxlength="300" value=""/>
    <input id="showonmap" type="button" value="show on map" onclick="codeAddress()"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I use JavaScript to click on **showonmap** button after pushing enter within **address** text input, but the problem is that right after that the whole form and its submit input works which I want to stop it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by *while entering within a text*

Comment: It was better to say while pushing "Enter" button.:)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, remove the input type submit and try something like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="a" name="a" type="text" />
    <input id="address" name="address" type="text" maxlength="300" value="" />
    <input id="showonmap" type="button" value="show on map" onclick="codeAddress()" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="myForm.submit()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your response. I did as you said but then all of my validations on form which were written with JavaScript stopped working.Do you know why this happened?

Comment: It depends on how the validators were attached. Were they looking for an input with type="submit" and attaching the logic there? You could also try to play with the form's onsubmit event and cancel submission there...